# Create an interface for heterogeneous sources

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I'm studying patterns writing my own examples. But sometimes I got stuck...

I have four stores:

**Store1: meat, ice cream and toilet paper.**

**Store2: ice cream.**

**Store3: meat.**

**Store4: ice cream, pasta, vegetables.**

Sometimes I want meat from all stores.

Sometimes only ice cream from all stores.

Sometimes only ice cream from a single store.

How should I design an **interface** for those classes considering not every method would be implemented in every class? I mean, there's no get_ice_cream for the **Store2** since **there's no meat in the Store2**.

Interface segregation could lead to an "interface explosion".

In other hand... people says that multiple inheritance is a bad decision in almost of cases.

I'm stuck trying to deal with that problem.

It would be very nice to have an way to add new Stores and make my **IceCream** concrete class be able to get all the ice cream from a list of **Store** objects simply executing the same **get_ice_cream** method.

Thanks for any help?

Comment: I'd consider composition. Stores that offer product A have it in their product list. You need really some application code to try to "do something" in an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a store factory that gives you each type of store.
Those stores should inherit from a generalStore abstract class that defines all those methods and return a *productNotFoundException* or whatever :)

In each store override what actually exists and when asking for a product, use a try/catch.

You could also have all products inherit from a general product that returns a product that has all getters return null before overriding.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I'm going to test it. Thank you very much for the suggestion!